# Подбор БД сжимающая (оптимизирующая) хранящиеся данные

Tags: база-данных

Стоит задача оптимально хранить данные так чтобы они занимали как можно меньше места на диске. Данные - просто массив int-ов (считаны с датчиков).

БД которые я нахожу заточены под быстрое извлечение данных и аналитик. У меня же не стоит задача быстрого извлечения (однако удобное извлечение без разархивирования файлов в ручную тоже необходимо).

Посоветуйте пожалуйста БД \ способы сжатого хранения данных с удобным (но не обязательно быстрым) их извлечением

Comment: Можно просто на сжатой файловой системе файлы БД хранить )

Comment: Ключевое слово для гуглинга - TSDB

Comment: *Данные - просто массив int-ов (считаны с датчиков).* Вот серьёзно? без номера датчика, штампа времени получения и т.п., одни голые инты? Ну храните как VARBINARY.

Comment: @Akina хранить сведения о массиве int-ов можно и в стандартной реляционной БД, а штамп времени не нужен т.к. интервал всегда одинаковы. Поэтому задача сводится к сжатию массива\массивов интов

Comment: @CrazyElf а не станет проблемой то что к БД есть постоянные подключения и пишутся по тысяче массивов в день? Я так понимаю если укладывать туда файлы, то они сожмутся, а если хранить саму БД, то не ясно как она будет сжиматься на ходу при появлении новых записей

Comment: *штамп времени не нужен т.к. интервал всегда одинаковы* Таблица БД - это куча, с неустановленным порядком взаиморасположения записей. Так что в случае, когда информация о порядке отсутствует в принципе, единственное компактное решение - это VARBINARY/BLOB, все значения в одно поле одной записи, и ориентироваться на физический порядок внутри одного значения. Кстати, это снижает накладные расходы на хранение. *хранить сведения о массиве int-ов можно и в стандартной реляционной БД* Именно о массиве - далеко не в любой. Да и накладные расходы на массив - а ведь нужна компактность.

Comment: @Akina спасибо, изучу использование VARBINARY/BLOB

Comment: @andreymal в том что такие БД хранят данные с временной меткой, это, конечно, хорошо, но в моей задаче требуется хранить именно крупные массивы int-ов без меток. Таким образом не ясно как TSDB могут сжать этот массив. Они будут хранить его в "первозданном" виде. Или я не прав?

Comment: @AleksandrSergeevich TSDB применяют различные хитрости для сжатия. Рассказывать всю матчасть в комментах пожалуй не буду, но например Prometheus [заявляет](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/1.8/storage/#chunk-encoding) о среднем размере 1.3 байта на одно число (chunk type 2). Или вам нужно как-то ещё сильнее сжать?

Comment: Вообще TS небось и RLE часто хорошо жмёт, в общем, методы могут быть разные, конечно.

Comment: Ради любопытства поэкспериментировал. MySQL 8.0.26, 128 млн. integers (больше текущие настройки сервере не позволили), упакованных в LONGBLOB, кушает на диске 778 метров.

Comment: @Akina хм.. 128млн int-ов это чистыми 488,28мб, на что ушли еще 37% пространста..

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, изучу Prometheus поглубже..

Comment: Дык эта... не забывай, что данные пишутся страницами. И освобождение страницы не означает, что она вотпрямсчас будет использоваться под очередные данные. В файлах данных таблицы всегда есть как незанятые блоки, так и незанятое пространство в блоках... тебя же не удивит, что на флэшке занято места больше, чем сумма длин файлов? тут та же история. *128млн int-ов это чистыми 488,28мб* да ну... а как по мне, так 512 метров. Инты - они все 4-байтовые.